# ros2 logging demo C++

Tags: ros, ros2, c++, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to migrate code to ROS2 and I am stuck on logging.

From https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Concepts/Logging/ I got to the code example at https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/logging_demo

My problem is that all the log calls use some unscoped get_logger(), or this->get_logger in one file. But I can't find where that is defined or what it is supposed to do. ( e.g. RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Publishing: '%s'", msg->data.c_str()); )

So 1) I don't get it myself atm 2) this is not a good practice for a demo that should clarify it.

Thanks in advance for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356743/ros2-logging-demo-c++/) by [Almost](https://answers.ros.org/users/28007/almost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-07-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

`get_logger()` is part of the API of `rclcpp::Node` [see the documentation](http://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Node.html#a884ebededa2125cb8316998852ca3fc5).

In the example is called  `RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), ...` or `RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), ...` because it's inside the class which extends the Node class. But if you want to use the logger outside a Node class you can use it in this way: `RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), ...`. Or if you don't have an available node you can called it: `RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("string of the logger", ... )

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50386/ahcorde/) with karma: 421 on 2020-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Almost](https://answers.ros.org/users/28007/almost/) on 2020-07-11**:
Perfect answer, thank you.
I think it would really be worth clarifying in the tutorial.